pgfplots: how to scale axes to have default width but half default height (overriding the default aspect ratio)?
I've read the pgfplot manual and understood that a plot will have a size of axisdefaultwidth x axisdefaultheight if not overwritten by width and height. When supplying either on, but not the other, the other is scaled to maintain the aspect ratio of defaultaxiswidth / defaultaxisheight. I now wish to create an axis half as high as the default axis. Setting just height causes the width to be altered, which is not what I want. Using the below MWE, I get an error that a height of 0.52pt is too small.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% Drawings & Figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis} [
                width=\axisdefaultwidth,
                height=0.5\axisdefaultheight,
                grid=major
              ]
                \addplot[smooth,domain=0:10] {cos(90*x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}


Package pgfplots Error:: Plot width `0.6037pt' is too small. This cannot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label sizes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your width..


\axisdefaultheight is a macro instead of a length, so you need to replace 0.5\axisdefaultheight with 0.5*\axisdefaultheight.  (TikZ runs almost everything through \pgfmathparse.)

Analysis
I can reproduce your problem with your code.
However, if I

set width and height e.g. to 10cm and 5cm manually, it works
replace the \axisdefault... by values manually, it works with your conditions, too


%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

% Drawings & Figures
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{figure}
%        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis} [
%                width=\axisdefaultwidth,
%                height=0.5\axisdefaultheight,
                width=240pt,
                height=103.5pt,
                grid=major
              ]
                \addplot[smooth,domain=0:10] {cos(90*x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{figure}
\end{document}

Suggestions
Simply put values, not the default macros.
Change your drawing strategy, i.e.:

have one file using class standalone and compile
use \includegraphics in your main document with whatever class suits you
see examples e.g. here
this gives you more freedom e.g. wrt scaling

Outlook
You could refactor the width and height into a \newcommand, see example below. If you write this line into a kind of configuration file AND \input it with every pfgplots drawing of this kind, everything will be fine or will change consistently (after all compiles are done).
However, I suggest to use larger values than the defaults. They already seem to be close to the smallest formats Tikz/pgfplots can handle.
With aboves standalone approach most of your scaling trouble will disappear anyway, after some setup research wrt main document.
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\myaspect[0]{width=240pt,height=103.5pt,}

% Drawings & Figures
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis} [
                \myaspect{},
                grid=major
              ]
                \addplot[smooth,domain=0:10] {cos(90*x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I currently input pgfplots into my main document, saving myself the duplicate preamble code and have a little bit more flexibility how the drawing is embedded into my main document (keyword: trim axis left, which, I believe, does not work when hard compiled). Thanks for the suggestions. An explanation, what exactly goes wrong would be welcome (also by other contributors).

IT is kown that TeX, which pgfplots and Tikz base on for widest compatibility, has numerical limitations here and there. If you want to find out, inspect the package codes.
